# Properties.Settings.Default.UserName.value == ""

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I don't know how to solve this. I have a loginform that sets this value and i want to check this in another form..

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.UserName.value == "" || Properties.Settings.Default.UserPass == "")
{
    loginForm.Show();
    //if (loginForm.IBContinue == true)
    //{
    //    //continue;
    //}
}
```

I have searched for this everywhere but cant find a solution for this..
Thankful for help..

Comment: Whats your error?  Try .value.tostring()

Comment: The problem is that it does not open..

Comment: Try trimming the values before using them

Comment: "The problem is that it does not open" what does not open? Where exactly is your problem? Does it not save settings in the login form? Or are you not able to read the settings in the main form?

Comment: Are you trying to open the `loginForm`?

Comment: Im trying to check if the settings.Username = null or ''' and if its this then the loginform will show and save the login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

"The problem is that it does not open". If you have a form called *loginForm* and you are trying to open it, then try this:

```
loginForm frm = new loginForm();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: The problem is that it does not check if the settings is null or '''.. i save the login credentials in the loginform.. i also call loginform.show() to open it..